# Cannot find home/seluser/Downloads folder in selenium docker container

Tags: selenium, docker

The following command:

```
docker exec [containerId] find /home -iname "*"
```

gives me:

```
/home
/home/seluser
/home/seluser/.bashrc
/home/seluser/.bash_logout
/home/seluser/.profile
/home/seluser/.local
/home/seluser/.local/share
/home/seluser/.local/share/applications
/home/seluser/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
/home/seluser/.sudo_as_admin_successful
```

Does anyone know why the `/home/seluser/Downloads` folder is not listed? I was able to access it a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

It was an error on my part. I forgot to run the following:

```
export DOCKER_HOST=docker
```